# Declare variable names from an array and then assign each variable as pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an array of string:

```py
sat_names = ['3254','3269', '3291', '3329', '3352', '3367', 
                  '3414', '3484', '3534', '3565', '3639', '3664']
```

I want to declare variable bearing the names as follows:

```
Msat_vir_cut_3254, Msat_vir_cut_3269 ... and so on
```

I have a function named `cut` that gives a pandas dataframe as output.

I want to assign the dataframe output of 'cut' function to the variable names using  a loop.

```py
## define 'cut' function
def cut(frame,val,f,log):
    if log == True:
        fac = np.log10(f)
        low_lim = np.log10(val) - fac
        up_lim = np.log10(val) + fac
        cut_df = frame.loc[(np.log10(frame) > low_lim) & 
                        (np.log10(frame) < up_lim)]
    else:
        low_lim = val - f
        up_lim = val + f
        cut_df = frame.loc[(frame > low_lim) & (frame < up_lim)]
    return cut_df
```

Example of cut function usage:

```py
Mh_sat = [3.28634047e+11 3.54157219e+11 3.28634047e+11 3.29435180e+14
 1.46750987e+12 1.65298123e+12 2.34478681e+12 4.23401172e+11
 2.47554291e+11 1.66607462e+11 1.36044543e+12 3.67648925e+12]

Msat_vir_cut_3254 = cut(data['Msat'],Mh_sat[0],3,True)
```

I want to iterate this process for all variable names as given in sat_names and for all Mh_sat values. sat_names and Mh_sat have same length i.e. 12

Answer (score 1):

Assuming cut(..) returns a dataframe,

```
sat_names = ['3254','3269', '3291', '3329', '3352', '3367', 
              '3414', '3484', '3534', '3565', '3639', '3664']
cut(...).columns = ["Msat_vir_cut_" + i for i in sat_names]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will elaborate a bit more on the problem:
The 'cut' function takes dataframe, a value from another array as input..
like: cut(df, array[i])

so, your suggested code becomes:
cut(df,i for i in array).columns = ["Msat_vir_cut_" + i for i in sat_names]

with this I am getting an error:  SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized


Any further suggestions?

Comment: You write in your question "I have a function named cut that gives a pandas dataframe as output." What does cut return? Please elaborate more in your question. cut(df,array[i]) is different from cut(df,i for i in array). Moreover "i for i in array" will not work as an argument to cut. What is the signature of cut?

Comment: def cut(frame,val,f,log):
    if log == True:
        fac = np.log10(f)
        low_lim = np.log10(val) - fac
        up_lim = np.log10(val) + fac
        cut_df = frame.loc[(np.log10(frame) > low_lim) & 
                        (np.log10(frame) < up_lim)]
    else:
        low_lim = val - f
        up_lim = val + f
        cut_df = frame.loc[(frame > low_lim) & (frame < up_lim)]
    return cut_df

the cut function returns a pandas dataframe as output

Comment: Mh_sat = [3.28634047e+11 3.54157219e+11 3.28634047e+11 3.29435180e+14
 1.46750987e+12 1.65298123e+12 2.34478681e+12 4.23401172e+11
 2.47554291e+11 1.66607462e+11 1.36044543e+12 3.67648925e+12]

is an array for which each item is to be iterated in cut function to get the output and then assign to the variable name

Comment: How many columns are there in the data frame that cut returns? Is it a fixed number every time? Is it 12 (I ask this because sat_names has 12 entries)?

Comment: No, the cut returns dataframe of different size but with single column [the cut function takes a fixed dataframe as input and selects only the values in range within a given fraction of a fixed value: the size of the output dataframe is dependent on the fraction and the value passed as input to the function], and then each dataframe output from cut needs to be assigned a variable name based on the sat_names string array

Comment: Please paste your cut function in the question. I can't see the formatting in the comments.

Comment: Also, good would be to include a sample input to cut and its output.

Comment: What do you mean by "No, the cut returns dataframe of different size but with single column"? Does the data frame always contain 1 column?

Comment: I have edited the question to explain all the details

Comment: Where is the sample input and output?